Laradock Can`t start mysql container
I'm configuring laradock, but I can't fix this error for several days. When I go to the adminer, or just go to the database somewhere, I get this error
php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

here are the logs from docker compose logs mysql:
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25 16:28:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.4.0-1.el9 started.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25 16:28:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25 16:28:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.4.0-1.el9 started.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25 16:28:55+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:55.679424Z 0 [System] [MY-015017] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - start.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:55.680681Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:55.680788Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.4.0) initializing of server in progress as process 81
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:55.682066Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:55.686133Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Error while setting value 'on else echo default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password' to 'mysql-native_password' -password'.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:55.686152Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010746] [Server] Parsing options for plugin 'mysql_native_password' failed.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:55.687018Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:55.896567Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:57.356697Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'mysql_native_password=on else echo default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:57.357142Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:57.357155Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
mysql-1 | 2024-05-25T16:28:58.918173Z 0 [System] [MY-015018] [Server] MySQL Server Initialization - end.

I reinstalled the entire kubuntu system a couple of times, downloaded from 0 laradock, but the same thing.
tried to solve in the following ways, but all in vain:
docker volume rm laradock_mssql

Also removed the entire mysql container but still the same

If you read the logs, what do you think "mysql_native_password=on else echo default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password" means? Is this in a configuration file? What should be there.

I don't know what this means, all I changed in the .env were these values
APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER=/home/[YOUR USER NAME]/Work
PHP_VERSION=8.2
PHP_FPM_INSTALL_EXIF=true
WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION=16
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_FFMPEG=true
PHP_FPM_FFMPEG=true
WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=true

laradock broke it, wait for a fix.

Who is interested, I wrote an issue in the laradock/laradock repository and there a man made a PR who fixed the bug.
The problem was conflicts due to the new version of mysql 8.4
https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/3523
